# Jquery Slimscroll not draggable in IE-9 and IE-10 when using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I saw similar questions but jquery slimscroll not drag-gable in IE-9 and IE-10 under follwing
conditions. 
Please use the js-fiddle link and add the given url's in External Resources field to test it.

//jsfiddle.net/rgmrw/11/

//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/ 1.4.2/jquery.js 
//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.3/jquery-ui.js

It's working fine in IE-8 and IE-11. I tried to find a solution but did't get any.

Update jquery versions will be a solution, but the thing is if we have to update we have to do  a major changes in our project and we are out of time. So if some one knows a optional solution to fix this please be kind enough to post it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally able find an answer, hope this will help for someone.
If we use a jquery-ui.js below the version 1.8.6 the slimscroll will not draggable in IE-9 and IE-10. If your project is not much implemented I suggest you to change your jquery-ui.js version, otherwise do the following change in jQuery-UI.js. It works for me.

```
_mouseMove: function(event) {
    // IE mouseup check - mouseup happened when mouse was out of window
    if ($.browser.msie && !event.button) {
        return this._mouseUp(event);
    }
```

as

```
_mouseMove: function(event) {
    // IE mouseup check - mouseup happened when mouse was out of window
    if ($.browser.msie && !(document.documentMode >= 9) && !event.button) {
        return this._mouseUp(event);
    }
```

or if you are using a minified file you can do the follwing change

> _mouseMove:function(a){if(c.browser.msie&&!a.button&&!(document.documentMode>=9))

only

> !(document.documentMode >=
>   9)

part should add additionally.
 
Found the answer comparing jquery-ui.js version 1.8.6 with my jquery-ui.js (1.8.3).

Answer (score 1):

Override the css class as such:

```
.slimScrollDiv {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```